# Separator line between columns in MS-Access report

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have successfully built a two column report in MS-Access (2013, if that matters). What I can't seem to find out, is how to get a separator line between the columns.

I have tried to draw a vertical line in the details area, but this is not working when some fields in the detail area can grow. The line does not grow, and there doesn't seem to be a "grow" option for lines.

What am I missing? If MS-Access does not offer this, is there a way to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your easiest solution is to create an image - about the size of your page - with a vertical line in the middle, then use that image as a page background for your report.
From my experience, the best quality/wheight you can get is when your image is in the EMF (enhanced Meta file) format, a Microsoft vector format.
This is not supported by many tools. I use Inkscape (free) when I need that. And from my limited experience, (free) Inkscape gives better results than (expensive) Illustrator for that use case.
Alternatively, you can create such background image as a Word document, save to PDF, then find an online PDF to EMF converter.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. I find it interessting (or should I say disappointing) that MS-Access does not support this out of the box.

Comment: CorelDraw can export to EMF format. I had to add rectangles with white background to the report, and page headers, and gthe page footer to hide the line in that area. But after all, that did the trick.

Comment: thx for feedback. Can you mark this as accepted answer ?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to edit your report in Design view, group the relevant controls, and then in the property sheet find the setting for gridline style left or right and change the setting to solid. You'll then have an effective separator line that extends along the control, no matter how much it grows.